# How can i use Toplevel method?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, toplevel

Hi I tried to use toplevel method in tkinter and it didnt work... 
What should i write to open two windows in different time in two methods, while there is method running in parallel?
the decide what method running in parallel with the receiving method... The code get stuck in the receiving method at "window = Toplevel(root)". Of course its get a message but I dont want to overflow you guys...

```
from Tkinter import *
import threading


def decide_what(self):

    global root
    root = Tk()

    root.title("options")
    root.geometry("600x250")
    root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)  # cant resize

    self.label = Label(root, text='CHOOSE YOUR FIRST OPTION!', font=30)
    self.label.place(x=200, y=13)

    self.button1 = Button(root, text='PrivateChat', font=30, 
    command=self.private)
    self.button1.place(x=1, y=50, width=200, height=199)

    self.button2 = Button(root, text='GroupChat', font=30, 
    command=self.group)
    self.button2.place(x=201, y=50, width=199, height=199)

    self.button3 = Button(root, text='BroadCast', font=30, 
    command=self.broadcast)
    self.button3.place(x=400, y=50, width=200, height=199)

    self.button4 = Button(root, text='WAIT', font=30, command=self.wait)
    self.button4.place(x=500, y=10)

    root.mainloop()


def receiving_message(self):  # a function that responsible to receive a message from the server, **shes in a class**

    print "receive??????????????????"
    while True:

        data = self.sock.recv(1024)

        data = decryption(data)
        print "data", data

        if data[:2] == "Br":

            print "got into br"

            window = Toplevel(root)
            print "window V"

            window.title("BroadCastZone")
            label = Label(window, text=data)
            label.pack()
            button = Button(window, text="ok", command=window.destroy)
            button.pack()

            print data
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not just getting stuck in the infinite loop?

Comment: The socket listener should probably run in a separate thread or process from the GUI. The 'while True' statement is a blocking statement, meaning it will prevent the event loop (root.mainloop) from processing events that update the display, create windows, etc. So you need a separate listener thread that communicates with the GUI, leaving the GUI available to format and display the results.

Comment: But its in a seperate thread... The GUI and the socket doesnt Collide

Answer (score 1):

All tkinter code needs to run in the same thread. If `receiving_message` is running in a separate thread, it can't create an instance of `Toplevel`. It will need to send a message to the main thread and ask it to open a window.

Comment: So if i have to do it like this new windows in threads is better?